# Why won’t my classic ASP page run in the root of my ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Here's my situation - I've had an ASP.NET application running in production for a long time now (Framework 2.0) and recently migrated from one root directory to another by switching the app's home path in IIS. Everything is running just fine, except any classic .asp scripts. When you hit them with a browser, they start to download like a standard text file.

The application config has not been changed, just the root home directory. Also, I have other applications on the same machine that do allow .asp to execute within them.

Before answering, keep in mind:
1 - this was all working in my ASP.NET app before I changed the home directory
2 - classic ASP is enabled
3 - classic ASP pages run from other virtual directories, so the extension mapping seems fine

Comment: Which version of Windows and IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after an AHA! moment, I found the problem.  Maybe this will benefit someone else since I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere in all of my searches.

It looks like another developer added an HTTPHandler to the web.config that was responding to all requests.

This prevented the asp.dll from processing the request for .asp files.  I'm still a bit stumped on why IIS is hitting the ASP.NET app before processing the ISAPI extension first.

Comment: Because ASP.NET actually **is** an ISAPI extension, so it probably had greater priority than the developer's one.

Answer (score 0):

Check if classic ASP pages are enabled at the virtual directory level; having them enabled globally or at the web site level could just be not enough.

Comment: Active Server Pages are enabled globally, and .asp is mapped to the asp.dll under ISAPI extensions at the virtual directory level.

Answer (score 0):

Does it even try to execute the vbscript in your .asp source file or is it returning the contents of the file to your browser as text/plain? Maybe you are missing some include file or something?

Comment: No, it doesn't execute.  Script contents are returned to the browser.